# Bash script pass in variable with new lines

Tags: bash

I have a script which runs a mysql query on multiple database. i have it logging the query which was run to a file. When i pass in the query it contains new lines, but in the log file its is all on one line. Multi line queries are easier to read.

e.g:

```
$ sh run_query.sh 'CREATE TABLE`table` ( 
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`field1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`field2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
 ENGINE=InnoDB;'
```

Is it possible for bash to keep the new lines in a passed variable?

Comment: The string itself is fine. The question is, how are you using (i.e., quoting) the parameter inside `run_query.sh`?

Comment: I am just using echo. e.g echo $sql >> logfile

Comment: I am simply echoing into a log file. but strange that a simple echo strips out the new lines. Is there a parameter to echo which will keep them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you mention using this code:

```
echo $sql >> logfile
```

However, this causes the shell to treat any newline character present in the value of `$sql` as whitespace to separate the string into multiple arguments for `echo`. You need to quote the expansion:

```
echo "$sql" >> logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store multiline string in a variable first like this:

```
IFS= read -rd '' sql <<'EOF'
CREATE TABLE`table` ( 
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`field1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`field2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
ENGINE=InnoDB;
EOF
```

Then pass it as:

```
sh run_query.sh "$sql"
```

Comment: There's no need to go through such contortions to set the value of `sql`. Newlines can be embedded in quotes as shown in the question.

Comment: Of course that may work but you understand very well a SQL can have single and double quotes and then this quoted string won't work.